# How to install SVN binary on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion, and now it looks like I need to reinstall the SVN client binary.  I realize I can do this via Homebrew, but isn't this also included in an Apple package in the Mac App Store?

I heard it was removed from the XCode package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode actually has SVN bundled in its .app directory. Its available at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn` (If you put Xcode.app in your Applications folder). You can add this path to your PATH, then access `svn` directly again.

If you need other Xcode command line tools (like gcc without installing Xcode), you can actually install them without installing Xcode first by going to [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), and download and install the Xcode Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have installed XCode, you can install SVN and other command-line utilities from the Downloads pane in XCode Preferences.

[image]